# returning different flutter widget depending on whether user is logged in or not

Tags: flutter, auth0

I am new to Flutter and would like to return the login screen or the home screen depending on whether the user is logged in or not. I am using auth0 for authentication and provider as the app state management solution.

I tried using context.watch but could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is logged in or not, general implementation for this flow is storing the token in persistent storage but in your case AuthO provides data/persistent token by itself in `Credentials? _credentials;`

Here is the implementation

```
//Declare the variables
Credentials? _credentials;
  late Auth0 auth0;
  
  ...
  
// Initialize them
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    auth0 = Auth0('{domain}', '{clientId}');
    errorMessage = '';
  }

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Auth0 Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Auth0 Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: isBusy
              ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
              : _credentials != null
                  ? Profile(logoutAction, _credentials?.user)
                  : Login(loginAction, errorMessage),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I want it to behave like this, except with auth0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xU5WH2kEc0&t=1274s